# pass parameters to route without the url in react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

im trying to render something like whatsapp,
in the main screen you got all the groups rendered, and when you click on a group then a new route become active and the main screen disabled,
i want that when the user click on the group (its a  object of course)
then the route that will respond to that event will somehow get the group object of the component that contain the  to the group.

ill show you a description of the code:

```
<Route exact path="/" render={props => (
    <GroupScreen groups={this.state.groups} />
)} />
<Route exact path="/conversation_area" render={props => (
    <h1>bla bla</h1>
)} />
```

in the groupsScreen component each single group component get a group object that related to her,
inside the group representation in the main screen you can click on it and it will route you to /conversation_area, now i know i can pass the name of the group in the url for example and than iterate over this.state.groups and this will work, but i wonder if there is a better way to communicate between link and a route...

the group component is simple, just a component that get a group object in his props, and a  that wrap all the design of the group.

thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the groups in state, you could filter state to only pass in the value that you want to.

```
<Route exact path="/conversation_area/:group_id" render={props => {
    // filter out the object that you need from the groups.
    const group = props.find(group => props.match.params.group_id === group.id)

    // you now have access to that group information.
    return (
        <h1>bla bla</h1>
)}} />
```

I'd restructure the code here and use the component prop to pass in a component. Keep the Routing simple, it'll save you a lot of hassle later on.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, did you ment in your code: this. state.groups.find(...)? In addition i wonder if there is a way to pass the prop without passing just the group id in the url, like a connection between the link components and the route

Comment: Im sorry, i dont quite understand what you asked.

Comment: Nevermind, i just was looking for a better way instead of iterating over the array and find the specific group that clicked by the used.